# Converting /vendor to Go Modules, cannot find module providing package error

Tags: go

Converting an existing project with a /vendor directory to use Go Modules (go version 1.12). I do `go mod init` to generate the `go.mod` file. Then I do `go get -u ./...` to populate the go.mod file. During this time, it tries to locate a package on github that no longer exists. It is vendored in my /vendor directory.

Until I can upgrade my code to use a different package, how can I continue the conversion to using modules? That is, I want to keep some things vendored (I also have some modified code under /vendor), while other things are handled by go modules.

Comment: Have you tried populating the `go.mod` file by just running `go build`?

Comment: Yes, same error ("cannot load github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss: cannot find module providing package github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss")

Comment: Or rather, `go build -mod=vendor` as recommended [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away)

Comment: Yes, that works. But that doesn't populate the go.mod file. My (perhaps mis)understanding is that using -mod=vendor just uses /vendor and doesn't touch go.mod at all. So I don't get any of the advantages of go modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix the `vendor` directory behavior and modules, each method of dependency resolution precludes the other. You can re-publish the missing package yourself somewhere that `go mod` can locate it, or you can redirect it directly to the existing vendored source in your module.

To redirect the source of a module, use the [`replace` directive](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-The_go_mod_file) in the go.mod file

`replace missing/package v0.0.1 => ./vendor/missing/package`